# TP-Link TG-3468 on an IBM x3850 M2

Tags: hardware, nic, ibm, ibm-xseries, pci-express

I got a networks card from TP-Link. It is the TG-3468. I wanna place it into my IBM server x3850 M2. It has PCIe x8 slots. The slot is a little bit longer than the lenght of the card, but it fits.
Also the BIOS shows, that there is an ethernet card there. But when I start, after initialising everything, the server shows a blinking _ sign.
Whats wrong and what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

First Check Boot Order in Bios..

You can disable the Ethernet-Bios launch for the PCI Slot of your card (guess you wont boot from this card) You can check this in IBM Bios.

If you reach the Bootloader and you try to Boot Linux then apply iommu=soft to Kernel boot flags